# Is it possible to do convex optimization with two decision variables? $\arg \min_{x,y} \enspace f(x,y)$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Quadratic programming problems, which are a type of convex optimization, typically only have one decision variable $x$

$$\arg \min_x \enspace f(x)$$

Is it also possible to solve for a second decision variable simultaneously?

$$\arg \min_{x,y} \enspace f(x,y)$$

If so, what are some examples and models that do multivariate convex optimization? What are some issues to be aware of when introducing a second decision variable $y$, compared to univariate quadratic programming,?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Not all quadrative programming problems are convex. Is $f$ a quadratic in $(x,y)$?

Comment: lets say it is convex. Can the solver solve two decision variables?

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking. The variable $x$ is in some $\mathbb{R}^n$. Just treat $(x,y)$ as a single decision variable in a larger space?

Comment: Its a simple question. Have you seen any quadratic programs that begin with $\arg \min_{x,y}$. If so, give some examples

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are looking for. $\min_{x,y} x^2+y^2$ is a convex quadratic program in two scalar variables. You could also write it as $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^2} x_1^2+x_2^2$ so whether you write it as $x,y$ or just $x$ doesn't really matter.

Comment: There are approaches to solving convex problems that explicitly alternate between solving the problem in one variable and then the other (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets for example). Again, I am not sure what you are really asking here.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are vectors

Comment: I understand, but you can treat $(x,y)$ as one big vector, so conceptually there is no difference between $\min_{x,y}$ and $\min_{(x,y)}$.

Comment: I see what you mean. do you know of any more example models (besides $x^2 + y^2$) that optimize for two decision variables (that are vectors)?

Comment: Some older approaches to VLSI global placement problems can be formulated as a QP over $x,y$ where $(x_k,y_k)$ represents the position of the $k$ the block.

Comment: Sometimes one encounters problems where the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is convex for a fixed $y$ and similarly when $x$ is fixed. In some of these cases a solution over $x,y$ can be found by successively solving for $x$, then $y$, then $x$, etc.